# Find the value that matches using ArrayList.contains() and them remove it from the ArrayList

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, linked-list, iteration

Say I have the following ArrayList:

```
a [1,3,5,7,9]
b [2,4,6,8,3]
```

So on iterating across a, if I do `b.contains(a.get[i])` then naturally I should get a hit at b[5]. Now, what I wish to do is basically remove that value that matches, in this case the 3 in ArrayList b. Is there any way to do this? It can save me a second pass across b.

Comment: [`b.removeAll(a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) will remove everything from `b` that is also in `a`

Comment: btw b[5] will throw ArrayIndexOutBoundsException.. index starts from 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

[List.removeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method will do the task

```
b.removeall(al)
```

> it removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in
>   the specified collection (optional operation).

is this what you want?

Comment: Wait... So I don't even have to do a .contains or anything?

Comment: Hmmm... but would this be prudent to use, in case of having say a hundred thousand rows?

Comment: No, but in that case you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` in the first place.

Comment: Any better data structure to use?